# Microsoft Teams: give the possibility to convert an adaptive card to image for NodeJS bots

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

Currently it's possible to convert an adaptive card to an image for Bots written in C#, but not for NodeJS.

This prevents the use of cards in many channels, like Facebook Messenger, Whatsapp and LINE, that accept only text and images.

On this topic there is currently an open GitHub issue at https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/930, but we ask to raise the priority of this request.

Regards, Damiano

Comment: P.S.: of course it would be even better if it would be possible to directly use adaptive cards in these channels

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to us! Please go ahead and raise a uservoice for the same [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/)